# Site definitions vs Web templates in SharePoint 2010 when using Feature Receivers

Tags: development

I've written some code which needs to be exacuted when creating a new site.
The site should look like something between a blank site and a team site. (Very basic)
And also uses a custom master page.

I thought of creating a Site Definition starting from the team site and stripping it down,
 and adding the code behind through a feature with feature receiver. (Would do it like this for 2007)
Is this a good approach for 2010 or should I create a Web template?

Does anyone has some guidelines/tutorials for creating team site Web Templates in VS2010?

Answer (score 3):

When working with SharePoint 2010 you should always try to use Web Templates instead of Site Definitions. The biggest benefit is the ability to update Web Templates and there are only a few edge cases when you would need to fall back to Site Definitions.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't specifically answer your Feature Receiver question. However, when looking at Side Definitions vs. Web Templates, I suggest you read [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms434313.aspx).

Comment: +1 for nice link